# Videojs controls are not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, dynamic-loading

I have a very strange with videojs.
I'm trying to load videojs similar to the documentation as a dynmical video tag.

```
videojs(document.getElementById('myVideo'), { "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto" }, function () {  });
```

My Videoplayer gets loaded, but when I click on an Item like the play button it doesn't do anything, it doesn't even throw an error.

So here is my VideoTag too:

```
    <video id="myVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="264">
    <source type="video/webm"
            src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm">
    <source type="video/mp4"
            src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.mp4">
    <source type="video/ogg"
            src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.ogv">
    <source type="video/flash"
            src="mp4:bauhaus/624x260.mp4">
</video>
```

Do anyone know, why I cant click on the control items?
It happends in Chrome, Firefox and InternetExplorer

Answer (score 0):

try to look at this demo
http://www.roughdesign.it/sof/videojs-demo/demo.html

I've used your video and works.
I don't know how is build your page so i can't tell you where is the problem

Comment: I load videojs via require.js and try to show the video in a lightbox plugin ( lightbox evolution ). I call videojs in the onOpen Event of lightbox: like      `$('.lightbox').lightbox({
    'onOpen': function () {
     videojs.options.flash.swf = "/js/videojs/video-js.swf";
     var vid = videojs(document.getElementById('myVideo'), { "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto" }, function () { this.bigPlayButton.hide(); });
     vid.controlBar.show();
    }
   });`